# Clearing A Dynamic Linked List with a Single Stored Element Crashes Program

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, linked-list

For my scholastic assignment I have been given the task of creating a Dynamic Set ADT using linked list. My program is functioning properly, but when I attempt to clear a Set which only has a single element (ergo, single node)my program crashes.

Here is how my linked list is defined:

```
typedef struct node{

    int value;
    struct node *next;

}Node;

typedef struct List{

    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
}*SetList;
```

And here are the relevant functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "List.h"

SetList ListCreate(){

    SetList lptr;
    lptr = malloc(sizeof(SetList));
    lptr->head = NULL;
    lptr->tail = NULL;
    return lptr;
}

SetList ListAdd(SetList lptr, int x){

    if(List_Is_Element_Of(x, lptr)){
            puts("Value already exists, enter a unique value");
    }
    else{
        Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        new->value = x;
        new->next = NULL;

        if(lptr->head == NULL){
            lptr->head = new;
            lptr->tail = new;
        }
        else{
            lptr->tail->next = new;
            lptr->tail = new;
        }
    }
        return lptr;
}


SetList ListRemove(SetList lptr, int x){

    if(lptr == NULL){
            puts("Memory Allocation Failed. Shutting down.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if(!List_Is_Element_Of(x, lptr)){
        puts("Value is not in set");
    }
    else if(lptr->head == NULL){
        puts("Set is empty. Cannot remove that which does not exist");
    }
    else{
        if(lptr->head->value == x){
        Node *tempnode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tempnode =  lptr->head;
        lptr->head = tempnode->next;
        free(tempnode);
        }
        else{
        Node *tempnode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tempnode =  lptr->head;
        Node *tempnode2 = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        tempnode2 = tempnode;
        while(tempnode->value != x){
            tempnode2 = tempnode;
            tempnode = tempnode->next;
        }
        tempnode2->next = tempnode->next;
        free(tempnode);
        }
    }
    return lptr;
}

SetList ListClear(SetList lptr){

    SetList templist = ListCreate();
    templist = lptr;
    while(templist->head!= NULL){
        ListRemove(templist, templist->head->value);
        templist->head = templist->head->next;
    }
    free(templist);
    return lptr;
}
```

I am not very experienced when it comes to pointers so I'm not entirely sure where the issue arises from. Removing a list with a single element stored works, but clearing it does not.

Thank you in advance for reading.

Comment: `sizeof(SetList)` is the size of a pointer, you want `sizeof(struct List)` or `sizeof *lptr`; I see at least three memory leaks in your code, you throw away the return values of `malloc`. Furthermore, you return freed pointers.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying when it comes to memory leaks as my lectures were not particularly good and I had to look up a lot of things online. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Your clear function doesn't change Tail, although you don't seem to use tail (except that you give it a different node than head when you add a node?).

When clear removes the last element, head should be null, so dereferencing it after removing that last element would be bad.

Plus what @NotLikeThat said.

Comment: You're right. So following your comment, I decided to loop while (lptr->head != lptr->tail), then after the loop I included another ListRemove(lptr, lptr->head->value) to remove the one remaining value and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading it right:

```
SetList ListClear(SetList lptr){

    SetList templist = ListCreate();   // Create a new list
    templist = lptr;                   // Immediately throw away the new list
                                       //  by overwriting the pointer with the old one
    while(templist->head!= NULL){      // Delete everything from the old list
        ListRemove(templist, templist->head->value);
        templist->head = templist->head->next;
    }
    free(templist);                    // Free the old list
    return lptr;                       // Return a pointer to freed memory
}
```

If you want to clear the list by removing all the elements, there shouldn't be the need to create a new one, just iterate over the existing list removing the elements until it's empty. All you really need in that function is the `while` loop.

I think `ListRemove()` should also be checking if it's removing the last element and updating `tail` accordingly if so.